# PHP insert into script returns 0

Tags: php, insert, insert-into

thats my second day working with PHP and MySQL.

I've got a problem. Im trying to create a new data in my db, but the only thing im getting is a 0 in the first field.(nummer)

```
 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","aufgabe");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$nummer = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['nummer']);
$vorname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vorname']);


$sql="INSERT INTO kontakte (nummer,vorname)
VALUES ('$nummer','$vorname')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Would you help me with that pls? I have now idea why nummer results in 0 and vorname in nothing.

I know that there is less security in my script, but it's only for school purposes.

Comment: Your script is actually fairly safe because you are correctly escaping your input. Some people will tell you to use prepared statements, but as a long-standing user of plain old `mysql_*` functions I'd tell you that as long as you're paying attention to what you're doing? Use whatever works!

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm actually just trying to understand php & mysql because i need to solve an exercise to get an apprenticeship. The only problem is that i never saw php & mysql before at my highschool, which is really frustrating. :D

Answer (score 0):

Check if `isset($_POST['nummer']) && isset($_POST['vorname']) == true` then `var_dump` both there variables to see what content to they have.

Comment: Aside: `if( isset($_POST['nummer'],$_POST['vorname']))` works too ;)

Comment: I added `if( isset($_POST['nummer'],$_POST['vorname']))` to my script and the only difference to the previous error is the line "Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\testinsert.php on line 17". Do i get it right? My script sends no information to the db?

Comment: @user3592201 You probably forgot to put `{...}` around your SQL stuff - my guess is that you only "applied" the `if` statement to the `$sql = ...` line, which results in it not being defined but trying to run anyway.

Comment: Actually thats my new code `if( isset($_POST['nummer'],$_POST['vorname']))
{
$sql="INSERT INTO kontakte (nummer,vorname)
VALUES ('$nummer','$vorname')";
}else{
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
}` ofc. not all of it but its the insert part